# Left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect when initialzing array of a struct

Tags: c

This is the pixel_t struct

```
typedef struct pixelType {
   unsigned char r;          /* red field                  */
   unsigned char g;          /* green field                */
   unsigned char b;          /* blue field                 */
} pixel_t;
```

I am trying to initialize a list of pixel_t structs but am getting an error saying Left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect. Here is where I initialize it:

```
pixel_t pixVals[8] = { (pixel_t)(255,255,255), (pixel_t)(255,0,0), (pixel_t)(0,0,255), (pixel_t)(128,0,255), (pixel_t)(0,0,0), (pixel_t)(0,255,0), (pixel_t)(255,128,0), (pixel_t)(255,255,0) };
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is:

```
pixel_t pixVals[8] = { {255, 255, 255}, {255, 0, 0},
```

etc.  Alternatively, at block scope you can use struct literals: `(pixel_t){255, 255, 255}`.

When you use parentheses you have an expression using the comma operator, which means to discard all but the rightmost operand.